# python loop through lists same dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a new list from keys and values of two different lists with dictionary's.
If key from a == key from b, then a['med']=b['med']...
It's working just for the last match, not all the matches :(
Thanks for any help.

```
list_a = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 8}, {'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}]
list_b =[{'f': 6, 'med': {}}, {'f': 1, 'med': {'g': 1, 'o': 60}}]

def get_event_and_med(list_a, list_b):
    list_updated = []
    for x in list_a:
        a_i = x.get('a')
        for i in list_b:
            b_i = i.get('f')
            if a_i == b_i:
                x['med'] = i.get('med')
            else:
                x['med'] = dict()
        list_updated.append(x)
    return list_updated

list_updated = get_event_and_med(list_a, list_b)
desired_output = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 8, 'med': {'g': 1, 'o': 60}}, {'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 7, 'med': {}}]
```

EDITED:

from the comments:

a) Code edited as suggested

b) get_event_and_med() called

c) desired_output provided

d) I don't want a big dictionary, that's why I want just to pic one key

e) I want to match every time.

f) If I give bigger lists, it won't match all, just the last:

```
list_a = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 8}, {'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}, {'a': 3, 'b':4, 'c': 9}]
list_b = [{'f': 6, 'med': {}}, {'f': 1, 'med': {'g': 1, 'o': 60}}, {'f': 3, 'med': {'g': 3, 'o': 85}}]
desired_output = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 8, 'med': {'g': 1, 'o': 60}}, {'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 7, 'med': {}}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 9, 'med': {'g': 3, 'o': 85}}]
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but your code would be much easier to read if you used dict literals, e.g. `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 8}` instead of `dict(a=1, b=2, c=8)`.

Comment: Also, where is `get_event_and_med` called? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you provide the desired output and the current output?

Comment: How much control do you have over how `list_b` is created?  You could instead create a mapping of `f` values to dictionaries, then do `for d in list_a: d['med'] = dict_b[d['a']]`

Comment: "It's working just for the last match" - this is because you continue to loop after finding a match, replacing it with any subsequent matches until only the last one is left. What do you want to happen when there is more than one match?

Comment: a) Code edited as suggested. b) get_event_and_med() called. c) desired_output provided. d) I don't want a big dictionary, that's why I want just to pic one key. e) I want to match every time.

Comment: I ran your script & I'm seeing same output as the one you mentioned in the "desired_output". What exactly are you trying to achieve ?